# Android app works fine in debug mode, but not in release (Generate Signed Bundle/APK)

Tags: ionic-framework, signed

I'd like to ask for some help with an Android issue my team is having with our Signed Build (.apk/.aab).

TL/DR:
The issue is that when we run our app locally un debug mode using ionic serve or Android Studio, we are able to login fine. But when we "Generate a Signed Bundle/APK" the app via a java keystone, we are unable to login.  It seem the login process cannot find the AuthToken on the phone, and so just quits.

Details:

- We have a mobile app built using ionic 5/Angular 8.  We are using the AuthConnect Enterprise plugin as well ("@ionic-enterprise/auth": "^3.9.2").
- We are using Android studio (2021.1 Patch 1).

Package.json (Below)

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx xxxxxxxx Mobile Version",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "author": "support@xxxx.app",
  "homepage": "https://www.xxxx.app",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npx jetifier"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.12.9",
    "@ionic-enterprise/auth": "^3.9.2",
    "@ionic-enterprise/camera": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic-enterprise/geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser": "^5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^5.31.1",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/open-native-settings": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.1.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.46.1",
    "capacitor-pdf-viewer-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3-hierarchy": "^1.1.9",
    "file": "^0.2.2",
    "firebase": "^7.14.3",
    "hawk": "^7.0.10",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "ngx-ionic-image-viewer": "^0.7.0",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.9",
    "rollbar": "^2.15.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.803.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "cordova-android": "^10.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "^1.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git",

    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "@ionic-enterprise/auth": {
        "AUTH_URL_SCHEME": "com.response.app",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location while this app runs only.",
        "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
        "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
      },
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am also attaching our config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="1" id="app.response" ios-CFBundleVersion="1" version="3.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <description>xxxx.app Mobile Application</description>
    <author email="support@reponse.app" href="https://response.app">xxxx Development Support Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="30" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="AIzaSyAm2VD_ypzfNZ1muaUirSXtOsplMft6O-0" />
    <preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_IOS_API_KEY" value="AIzaSyBoWBCEoKbAXNffdYfC8-0nZcrHgIfxEH0" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>Camera usage needs to be enabled on the device in order to upload photos of an incident.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
            <string>Required to access the user’s photo library.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
            <string>Required to access the user’s photo library (iOS 14+).</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string>Location/GPS services are required in order to pinpoint your location on the map during an incident.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^6.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^6.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.2" />
</widget>
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I managed to figure out the issue.  We identified that our authentication API was not being hit.  This lead us to look at the `Resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml` file.

I found this link very helpful:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://xxxx-prod.xxxx.com</domain>
    </domain-config>

    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>

</network-security-config>
```